# Детский вопрос: почему Ошейник, а не НАшейник?

Tags: грамотная-речь, словообразование, приставка

У нас в доме есть пёс.
Ребёнок спрашивает: "Одевать ему **на**шейник?"
Из раза в раз я поправляю: "Не нашейник, а **о**шейник".

**На**ручник, **на**коленник, **на**грудник, **на**пёрсток...
А почему — ***о**шейник*?

Comment: Частица "о-" также используется для ["вокруг"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/о-).

Answer (score 2):

Приставка О имеет два значения:1) сделать каким-либо,превратиться в кого-либо, снабдить чем-либо и 2) действие, которое распространяется на всю поверхность, охватывает его кругом или распространяется на ряд предметов: охватить, оклеить, окольцевать, опутать.

Ошейник не висит на шее, а охватывает, окружает её.

Comment: Но наручник, наколенник, налокотник тоже не висят,  а охватывают.  Почему же нельзя сказать "нашейник"? По логике ведь правильно. На чём же основан выбор одной или другой приставки?

Comment: налоко́тник, наплечник, наколенник, нашейник - элементы доспехов, накладки на часть тела для их защиты, они не целиком охватывали эту часть тела,  потом появились другие значения -налокотник как лоскут из ткани, кожи, нашиваемый на локтевой сгиб рукава одежды для предохранения от изнашивания, в том числе и нашейник как украшение на шею, хотя было уже русское ожерелье - охватывающее шею. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/193072/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA. Видимо, чтобы отличить украшение человека от кольца на шею раба, придумали  ошейник(и для животных)

Answer (score 0):

Всё предельно просто. Если предмет защищает **поверхность тела** в какой-то области, **накладывается** **на эту поверхность**, то используется приставка НА (на шею).

Всё, что просто **окружает шею** с какой-то целью, имеет приставку О (вокруг шеи). Ожерелье – для украшения, ошейник – для крепления поводка.

Слова же в языке обычно **"не придумываются" кем-то** (хотя и такое бывает), а возникают стихийно в сознании людей, отражая назначение того или иного предмета.

Comment: "Всё предельно просто". М-м... *Наручники* никаким образом не защищают поверхность тела.